# Re-installing default video driver?

Tags: drivers, video

I am experiencing quite major problem with Ubuntu 11.10.

Here is what happened:
I installed the closed source video driver suggested by Ubuntu (my graphics card is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 560v). 
Having installed the driver I restarted the computer, and after that some parts of the Gnome UI didn't show up properly, wrong colors & unclear. 
I decided to remove the driver installed as everything had worked before installation, again rebooted my computer, but this time after showing the purple boot screen, whole screen turns black and nothing happens.
I tried restart couple of times, same black screen instead of login screen.

The recovery mode of Ubuntu works so I can access terminal, only problem is that I don't know what to do.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have followed this guide to correctly install the proprietary driver http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

Also notice that there is a section of FAQ about problems and solutions, take a look at "Problems Starting Xserver"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the replies, I found solution from Micro's answer. It was in [the wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide) in the section you suggested.

All I had to do was run this command:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.disabled
```

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get purge fglrx` and maybe `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, delete everything and save with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.